# Circuit Breaker envoy proxy

Tags: circuit-breaker, envoyproxy

I am going to setup an envoy proxy, but still confused about the Circuit Breaker. For example: `max_connections` (*UInt32Value*) is the maximum number of connections that Envoy will make to the upstream cluster. If not specified, the default is 1024.

Does that mean it will limit `max_connections` per hosts in cluster or limit `max_connections` per cluster?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Circuit breaker is a cluster attribute and `max_connections` will apply to all hosts that form a cluster. The Envoy's circuit breaking mechanism is fully distributed (not coordinated).

Meaning for example, if you set `max_connections` for http1 to 1024 then this global value will apply to all hosts. The hosts in the cluster have 1024 cakes to share and not more.

Best source is the documentation: [Envoy: Circuit Breaking](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/upstream/circuit_breaking#arch-overview-circuit-break)